# How to get language of user - navigator.languages not working

Tags: javascript, localization

I am using `navigator.language || navigator.userLanguages` for getting language of user.

On chrome, IE this code returns `cs-CZ` but in firefox, it returns `cs` but it is wrong. The expected return is `cs-CZ` not short form `cs`.
(for Czech language).

How can I get full language form in firefox?

So, or there is some npm library for this?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this instead:

```js
console.log(navigator.languages ? navigator.languages[0] : (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage))
```

This is because for Firefox, `navigator.languages` returns an array of strings, which represents the preferred languages, so you will end up with something like `["en-US", "en"]`.

Comment: Same problem in Firefox (66.0.3 windows 64b)

Comment: Can you please try this instead, and let me know the results? `console.log(navigator.languages)`

Comment: console.log(navigator.languages) - Array(4) [ "cs", "sk", "en-US", "en" ]

Comment: Ok, here is one last shot. `console.log(window.navigator.language))`. Here is a disclaimer: it returns the preferred language, which may or may not be the browser UI's language. Thought usually they are the same..

Comment: window.navigator.language - "cs".

So, ok, I understand. :/